# login page's error with database retrieval

Tags: java, database, authentication

ive been working on a login page connected to a mySQL database and it keeps on trigerring the "Incorrect username or password alert".

ive printed all the values that it is getting and cannot find out where i am wrong.

my table is setup in a way that bcsapril is the first entry in the table and it prints out that the username from the textfield is not equal to the retrieved value from the database.
and ive tried to change the
if(rs2.next())
into
while(rs2.next())

the next frame showed up but im getting the 'incorrect' message the same number of times as the number of entries in the database.

my only question is why is it that "bcsapril" is always the username that my code is retrieving. any help would be great.

```
if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
  String user = userTx.getText();
  String pwd = new String (passTx.getPassword());
  String sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts";
  boolean loggedIn = false;

  try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dardb","root","1234");
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs2.next()) {
            String uname = rs2.getString("username");
            String password = rs2.getString("password");
                if((user.equals(uname)) && (pwd.equals(password))){
                    loggedIn = true;
                }
        }

        if(loggedIn){
             DarDBMainFrame x = new DarDBMainFrame();
                    x.setVisible(true); 
                    java.awt.Dimension screenSize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
                    setBounds(0,0,screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
                    setVisible(true);
                    x.setUsername(user);
                    pack();      
                    setUser(user);
                    dispose();
        }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Incorrect Username or Password!", "Login Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    System.out.println(user);
                    System.out.println(pwd);
             } 
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | HeadlessException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from @Ravi's answer, if you must loop, I'd suggest the following (extraneous code removed for clarity):

```
boolean loggedIn = false;

while(rs2.next()) {
    if((user.equals(uname)) && (pwd.equals(password))){
        loggedIn = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!loggedIn) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Incorrect Username or Password!", "Login Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: same thing :(
logging in but still displayed "Incorrect username and password" 4 times

Comment: Are you positive that you have the "Incorrect username and password" outside of the while() loop?

Comment: If it is being displayed 4 times then you are inside the loop. 100%. You should have flag variable inside loop. If you find 1 match, set flag to true. If you find no match, set flag to false. Once you are out of loop, display appropriate msg. BTW, if you find the match, break the loop on the spot. Can you post the updated code ?

Comment: yes sadly i placed the msg in the same loop used to check username matches. ive added the boolean flag and did apropriate actions outside the while loop. We are all good!  i may have more questions later :)

Answer (score 0):

Without running the code, I suspect the issue is because you're not providing a `where` clause to the SQL to restrict the results to the provided username.

Instead, you're selecting all results from the table and only retrieving the first (via `rs2.next()`).

A more common approach would be to:

1. Create a prepared statement of the form:

   `SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = ? and password = ?`
2. Set the first parameter in the prepared statement to be the username input by the user, and the second parameter to be the user's password
3. Determine how many rows are returned - if there is one result, then you can deem authentication successful

A sample (untested) code extract for the prepared statement could be:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username=? AND password=?";  
Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dardb","root","1234");
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);

statement.setString(1, uname);
statement.setString(2, password);

ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
```

Side note once you've got this working - you should really not be storing plain text passwords in the database - try using something like a SHA-1'd value at the very least.

Note that I'm suggesting a prepared statement rather than placing the username and password directly into the SQL in order to guard against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: this is very useful, however can you please elaborate on the SHA-1'd value that you are suggesting. i know and feel that that can help me in the future

Comment: It's a way of storing a value in a way that can't easily be read by a human. For example, if somebody malicious got hold of your database, they won't be able to harvest the passwords of all of your users. It's not foolproof, but it's significantly better than plain text.

Comment: i see. like encryption. gotto look unto that sooner or later. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It should be `while(rs2.next)` not `if(rs2.next)` because you are retrieving all the records from *Accounts* table.

If you were supplying **where** clause in your SQL statement then **If** condition would be alright.

Comment: yes ive done that however the "Incorrect user/pass" window still appears 4 times(same number of entries in the accounts table) after succssfully displaying the next frame

Comment: This is because for each (non-matching) record in the table, you are falling through to the `else` block. If you really do want to iterate through the whole table, you should instead take the error condition outside of the loop and only display the text if no match is found.

Comment: i know this is something basic but im really confused on where to place the else block since i need to check every entry in the table. thank you so much for the patience btw